# Android - Bring an activity to the front from application class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bringtofront

I am trying to bring an activity to the front. I found many questions similar to this but none of them actually works.

I always hold a reference to the current activity in a variable in application class. While the application is running in the background (after onPause fires), if any message arrives, I need to bring the same activity to the front and display the message. The only way I got it worked is..

```
Intent i = new Intent(mCurrentActivity, JoboffersActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

The issue I have got with this, is that it recreates the activity which I wanted to avoid. I tried `singleInstance` and `singleTask` both in the manifest. If I do not add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, on back key press it takes me to the previous instance of the same activity. Even if I add `sigleInstance` it creates two instances of the same activity. If I do not add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` then it shows an error Calling `startActivity()` from outside of an Activity context requires the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag

Comment: Why can't you show a notification? I would be very annoyed if an app suddenly opens itself in front of whatever I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add another flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP to your intent.
According to Android documentation, combination of this 2 flags:

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

brings the current instance of Activity to the front.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP